# Open xterm telnet connection (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, applescript, x11, telnet, xterm

I have been trying to get this script right for hours and came pretty far, but i'm stuck by passing commands to the X11 xterm window.

I need a connection to an xterm telnet server. This is the normal procedure:

- open Terminal
- type the command: `xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12` (This opens an X11 window, with a bigger font)
- in the new xterm window i type: `telnet -l username server ip`
- this opens the telnet connection and prompts for the password

because some users w/o terminal knowledge have to have access to this connection i tried several approaches to write a script that would run on a Mac. And open the connection to let users work in the opened telnet window. I ended up with using AppleScript for that, and wrote the following script:

```
tell application "X11"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "X11"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu "Applications"
                click menu item "Terminal"
                tell window 1
                    run
                    do script "xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12"
                    delay 2
                    do script "telnet -l meister 192.169.25.1"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. It only opens an X11 xterm window, w/o the bigger fonface, and w/o the terminal command, it is just an empty window.

Does someone of you have a idea how i could change the script so it works, or maybe there is a way to do it with some other type of script rather that AppleScript?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using Terminal to open xterm? Why don't you just create the telnet session in the Terminal application? If you did that, there are several ways to create shortcuts for opening a telnet session in Terminal, and you can arrange for the font or other appearance settings to be set the way you want.

Comment: Hi Chris, i'm not using the terminal because it causes an error when i try to connect to the server:

Comment: this is what i get:

"Fehler beim Oeffnen von </gewa/diwaprg/ariadne/v3term/xterm-256color> 2

-Fehler beim Oeffnen von </gewa/diwaprg/ariadne/v3term/xterm-256color> 2
AMASK : Datei /gewa/diwaprg/ariadne/v323tc/xterm-256color kann nicht eroeffnet werden !
AMASK : Variable TERM richtig gesetzt ?

DIWA: Fehler nach Aufruf MEDIWA (1)
DIWA    : </gewa/diwaprg>
MANDANT : </gewa/GEWA-DB>
AMASKDIR: </gewa/diwaprg/amd>
Connection closed by foreign host. "


With xterm it works ;)

Comment: You may just need to set the TERM environment variable (and possibly TERM_PROGRAM) in your login scripts on the remote machine, or in the Terminal Profile (the "Report Terminal Type" option menu somewhere in the Profiles Preferences). In fact, your best bet may be to create a Terminal profile that starts with the command "telnet -l meister 192.169.25.1" instead of your login shell.

Comment: @abarnert, right. That error means that the xterm-256color terminfo files are not installed on the remote host. The best solution is to install them. Barring that, customize the value of the `TERM` environment value to something that *is* installed on the remote host. The most robust way to do that is to configure the shell on the remote host to check for xterm-256color and map it to one that exists. The simplest solution is to manually set the environment value when invoking telnet on the local host. You can wrap it in a shell function in your local shell startup script for convenience.

Comment: Note (because lots of people get this wrong): Avoid using `xterm-color`, because that represents an older branch of xterm that has some incompatibilities with modern xterm and Terminal. Prefer `xterm-88color`, `xterm-16color`, `xterm` in that order if `xterm-256color` is not installed. Only use `xterm-color` if you’re using Terminal on OS X prior to Lion 10.7 (`xterm-color` is a better match for older versions of Terminal prior to 10.7, but a much worse match for 10.7 and later).

Comment: @ChrisPage: +1. But if you're using Terminal, can't you create a new Settings profile with (e.g.) "Declare terminal as: xterm" as well as your favorite font, etc., settings and just use the "Run command" feature to run telnet directly, instead of running your login shell and a shell function? (I'll admit that I rarely use Terminal; I know iTerm much better…) Anyway, I think you should put this all together into an answer. It's not exactly what the OP asked for, but it's definitely a better way to get what he actually wants than my suggestion.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, you can create a settings profile with the desired TERM value and the telnet command. Creating a new terminal with that profile will start the telnet session.

Answer (score 5):

First, to launch the xterm just do this:

```
do shell script "xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12 -wf"
```

This will automatically launch X11 if needed.

Depending on your system, /usr/X11/bin may not be on the path, so you may want to do this instead:

```
do shell script "/usr/X11/bin/xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12 -wf"
```

And if you want xterm to run a command instead of just opening a shell, use the -e parameter:

```
do shell script "/usr/X11/bin/xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12 -e telnet -l meister 192.169.25.1"
```

If the telnet command fails, the xterm window will close instantly; to debug that, add a "-hold" before "-e".

Since you asked about "some other type of script rather than apple script", the same thing is obviously a one-liner in bash, two with the shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/X11/bin/xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12 -e telnet -l meister 192.169.25.1
```

If you save that as "doit" and "chmod +x doit", you can run it from the Terminal as "./doit".

Or, if you want it double-clickable in Finder, rename it to "doit.command".

Comment: On Snow Leopard I get this error: error "sh: xterm: command not found" number 127

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, it is so funny that all it takes is one line of code! And i tried hours and with sveral lines to come out with my non working script ;)

Comment: I only have one problem, maybe i did something wrong.
 The apple script gives the error: "sh: xterm: command not found"
/ The other script, (i saved it as a file namend doit.command), gives the error "the file could not be executed because you dont have apropirate priviliges" but under "get info" i have read/write access 

sorry i guess this clould be a "stupid" question but i couldn't find the sulution myself and i couldn't find anything on google.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!

Comment: You need xterm to be on your path for this to work. Depending on how you installed X11 or configured your system, this may not be true. So you may be safer explicitly doing "/usr/X11/bin/xterm" instead. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, I believe to run a script as a .command file from Finder, you still need to have execute permission (not just read and write), just as you do to run it from the command line. I don't know how to set this in Finder, but from the command line, it's the same "chmod +x doit.command".

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
tell application "X11"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "X11"
        click menu item "Terminal" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Applications" of menu bar 1
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "xterm -fa Monaco -fs 12"
        delay 0.5
        keystroke return
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "telnet -l meister 192.169.25.1"
        delay 0.5
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This is a bad idea for a number of reasons. For example, if X11 wasn't already running, activating it will create a default xterm window, after which you'll create a second one, leaving the original also open. And if it takes longer than 0.5 seconds to start, the rest of the command will fail. Similarly, if the xterm takes more than 0.5 seconds to come up and grab key, the telnet will go to the Terminal window. Sometimes there's no way around UI scripting and the problems that come with it, but in this case there are many better alternatives.

Comment: good points. I used GUI because X11 is not scriptable. I should have checked Terminal first. +1

Comment: Yes that xterm is not scriptable was also a huge problem for me, because at first i clouldn't understand why my commands didn't work!